# Repository Pattern: How many repositories are needed to get a Contact with two Addresses?

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern

If you have one Contact, with a 1:* relationship with Addresses, and possibly one or more other tables used to hold the persisted value objects -- how many repositories should there be?

Should there be just one ContactRepository with one public method (GetContact(), that internally calls a private method (GetAddresses)) that returns a fully hydrated entity (Contact+Addreses)?

Or should there be two Repositories -- one For Contacts, one for Addresses with the COntactsRepository calling the AddressRepository?

Or other?

Thank you!

Comment: BTW: The reasons I ask is that...if all clumped together, with larger object trees, we soon get to bad God Classes. 

On the other hand, if separated, how does one efficiently get all contacts that have an address on Mulberry road?

Another option is to consider a Repository + helper classes to break it down a bit...but there is still some cross over (the Mulberry drive example) which I don't know where to put. 

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Can anything other than a Contact have an Address?

If not, I'd probably think about having just a ContactRepository.

If there also exist entities like Orders, Events, etc, that have Addresses, I'd think about a separate AddressRepository.

Your Mulberry road/drive example implies that you only want one address record for "123 Mulberry Rd", no matter how many Contacts have that address, that might well create more impetus to do an AddressRepository.

Comment: Tim. Thanks very much. I think you hit it on the nail that it is a matter of need more than anything.

I think the guiding decising is what is needed from a Domain point of view: Currently the Domain is dealing with Contact entities only. Up till the point that the DOMAIN starts to talk in Addresses as well (as Entity objects in their own right, and not Value Types), it remains just needing at best its own AddressTable class (for SOP reasons) without needing to be exposed as a full blown Repository. Thanks.